# how to use single Iterator reference for showing data from ArrayList in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, iterator

how to use single Iterator reference for showing data from ArrayList in java .

here is my code,

```
    String names="Nachan,Ram,Ganesh,Kumar,Prasanna";
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] nameList=names.split(",");
    for(int i=0; i<nameList.length-1; i++)
        list.add(nameList[i]);

    Iterator<String> nameitr=list.iterator();
    while(nameitr.hasNext())
        System.out.println(nameitr.next());

    while(nameitr.hasNext()) //here error occurs 
         System.out.println(itrall.next());

/* why here i can't use the same or another iterator reference for the particular list */
```

Comment: First, your program wouldn't compile because of the reference to a nonexistent variable `itrall`. Second, the line marked `here error occurs` woudn't give you an error, `hasNext()` would just return `false` because you've already iterated through the whole list in the previous loop, so the iterator has no more elements to give you, thats why you can't reuse it.

Comment: thank you so much Andrew Lygin.  so, is there any other way to get them all from starting index by using Iterator

Comment: You need to create another iterator on the same list.

Comment: thank u so much. another iterator is the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the below statement executes, an Iterator `nameitr` will be created over the ArrayList object `list`.

```
Iterator<String> nameitr=list.iterator();
```

when we do `nameitr.next()`, `nameitr` will point the 1st element or the ArrayList. Likewise the loop executes until the `nameitr.hasNext()` is false. That means `nameitr` is pointing to the last element or the Arraylist and there are no more elements left in the Arraylist to point.

As the `nameitr` is already pointing the last element of Arraylist, the below line of code returns false.

`while(nameitr.hasNext()) //here error occurs`

To avoid this, we need to create a new iterator over the arraylist

`Iterator new_nameitr2=list.iterator();`

or we need to re-initialize the existing iterator as below so that the iterator `nameitr` will be pointed to the 0th element of the Arraylist .

`nameitr=list.iterator();`

Comment: Thank you @S McCrohan and Mr.Vijay.gv. **re-initialization** is the one of the best way to use the same reference .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you won't get the last element. You should place an equal sign.

```
for(int i=0; i<=nameList.length-1; i++)
    list.add(nameList[i]);
```

Secondly, you have to use another iterator as the first iterator have reached end. 
You can do this:

```
Iterator<String> nameitr=list.iterator();
while(nameitr.hasNext())
    System.out.println(nameitr.next());

Iterator<String> nameitr1=list.iterator();
while(nameitr1.hasNext())
    System.out.println(nameitr1.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

When the below statement executes, an Iterator nameitr will be created over the ArrayList object 'list'. 
        Iterator nameitr=list.iterator(); 
when we do nameitr.next(), nameitr will point the 1st element or the ArrayList. Likewise the loop executes until the nameitr.hasNext() is false. That means nameitr is pointing to the last element or the Arraylist and there are no more elements left in the Arraylist to point. As the nameitr is already pointing the last element of Arraylist, the below line of code returns false.
        while(nameitr.hasNext()) //here error occurs

To avoid this, we need to create a new iterator over the arraylist Iterator

```
    new_nameitr2=list.iterator();
```

or we need to re-initialize the existing iterator as below so that the iterator nameitr will be pointed to the 0th element of the Arraylist .
        nameitr=list.iterator();